# Display array of movieclips and dynamically update them?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

So I have this Array, named combo. I want to fill it with movieclips according to the user clicks (if user clicks 1, then add "1" to the Array and display it on an area.

Problem is, I do not know how to do it.

For the record, I have 4 movieclips, fire, wind, earth and spirit. When the user clicks one of them, I want the Array to update. Array's max length is 6 and it is always checked against a "true_combo" Array.

My questions are:

```
1) How do I remove the oldest item in the Array if the length has reached 6?
2) How do I display the movieclips one next to another (smaller versions of the buttons, not new movieclips), according to Combo?
3) How do I dynamically update the movieclip list on the stage?
```

This is a stripped version of my current fla
https://www.dropbox.com/s/17d9rgclz29ft1u/Untitled-1.fla

This is the code to check the combo against true combo:

```
function checkthis(e:Event)
{
    if(combo.length == truecombo.length)
    for(var o:int = 0; o < combo.length; o++) 
    {
        if(combo[o] == truecombo[o])
        {
            bravo.play();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show us what you have tried that isn't working and we'll help you fix it

Answer (score 1):

**1**
You can use the `Array.shift()` (remove first item in array) or `Array.pop()` (remove last item in array)

**2 / 3**
Use a for-loop and change the position of the items according the array. I assume the items in the array are references to the movieclips, then this would be functions you could use.

```
function add(clip:DisplayObject)
{
    if (this.combo.length >= 6) 
{
    // remove child and remove it from the list
    removeChild(this.combo.shift());
}
this.combo.push(clip);
this.addChild(clip);

    reorder();
}

function reorder()
{
   for(var i:int = 0; i < combo.length; i++)
   {
       combo[i].x = i * 50;
   }
}
```

---

**update:**
You can download an example of this implementation [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6212130/stackoverflow/add-and-order.fla) (Flash CS6 file) or watch it [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6212130/stackoverflow/add-and-order.swf)

---

**update 2**

```
function checkthis(e:Event)
{
    var isValid:Boolean = true;
    if(combo.length == truecombo.length)
    {
      for(var o:int = 0; o < combo.length; o++) 
      {
        if(combo[o] != truecombo[o])
        { 
            // if one item isnt the same it should fail.
            isValid = false;
        }
      }
    }
    if (isValid)
    {
        bravo.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is on the right track...it adds the movieclips in order without messing them up, but it does not limit them to 6, nor does it rearrange them.

Comment: You have to give some more information about how/what you've implemented it and what went wrong. You can add an update to the original question.

Comment: As I mentioned, the initial positioning happens well, but when the list reaches 6, it does not get limited to 6 on the next update, rather, it keeps adding the movieclips...so I end up with a lot of movieclips in the array instead of 6 maximum...also they do not change their initial position (which should happen when they get over 6, right?)

Comment: Wow man...this code totally screwed up things. Worse than before! You know what? I know I've been a pain in the ass, but if there is ANY hope you could check my fla and give me some help here, I'd appreciate it...

Comment: You have to look at the example fla file, check how it works. Is that how it is supposed to work? Then again, you have to tell how youve implemented it. Yes you could add the fla, but if you want to learn why its wrong, you first need to learn to describe what is wrong, then analyze where it could be wrong, then learn how to fix it. Just saying this, because your comment is totally unhelpful. I think thats unfair, since I spend time helping you.

Comment: The FLA you posted is actually exactly what I want to do (except for the delay). I used exactly your code from your answer, (I did change the name of the function to add1 because add seemed to be a system word). Now the symbols get totally screwed up, some start at 0,0, some other go to the bottom of the screen randomly (seemingly), and of course the 6 max limit is out of the window. I'm sorry that my comment was bad, I was very frustrated at the moment, I apologize. I cannot guess what's wrong since I have very limited knowledge of AS3, so I posted the fla just in case you could take a look.

Comment: I've looked at the file, fixed the code, added some comments. Hope that helps. Have fun!
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6212130/stackoverflow/add-and-order-fixed.fla
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6212130/stackoverflow/add-and-order-fixed.swf

Comment: It actually helps a lot! It works as expected...however I can't check the two arrays (combo, truecombo)...check my question for the check code.
Note, bravo does not play, which means it doesn't work so I can proceed!

Comment: Well you have to count the good ones in the if-statement. If they are the same length as the combo.length, its the same.

Comment: This is what I supposedly do, if you could maybe check this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755936/how-to-compare-2-arrays/13774597#13774597)

Comment: You are kinda lazy or you should hire a developer. But since I'm in a good mood, I've updated my post again.