# How to compare 2 arrays?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, compare

I have two arrays, namely combo and truecombo. The user fills the combo with MovieClips by clicking on various buttons on the stage, truecombo is the correct combination.

At any given point (enterFrame) Flash is checking whether the two are the same, if yes, then do some stuff. For the time being this is my code (altered several times, like with Typecasting the indices, adding .parent at the end of combo[o] etc. 2 things will happen, either one or the other.

Either the statement will not be satisfied, at which point the adding and chopping of the combo array will continue, or the condition will be instantly met when combo.length = 6. Check my code.

**UPDATE: I have a dropbox file with my current code. Click this for FLA [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/17d9rgclz29ft1u/Untitled-1.fla) and here is the SWF [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eb5j7rm7ozh73dx/Untitled-1.swf) stripped down as always for ease and security.**

```
/*stage.*/addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkthis);
function checkthis(e:Event)
{
    for(var o:int=0;o<= combo.length; o++) 
    {
        if((combo[o] == truecombo[o]) && (combo.length==truecombo.length))
        {
            equal=true;
        }
    }
    if (equal==true)
    {

        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkthis);
        endSeq();
    }
}
function endSeq():void
{
    bravo.play();
    for (var i:int = 0; i < combo.length; i++)
    {
        var element:DisplayObject = combo[i];
        element.parent.removeChild(element);
    }
    firebb.gotoAndPlay(2);
    windbb.gotoAndPlay(2);
    spiritbb.gotoAndPlay(2);
    earthbb.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

This is how I push my new elements to the combo array.

```
function add(element:DisplayObject)
{
    twist.gotoAndPlay(2);

    element.width = WIDTH;
    element.height = HEIGHT;

    if (this.combo.length >= MAX_ELEMENTS)
    {
        removeChild(this.combo.shift());
    }

    this.combo.push(element as DisplayObject);
    this.addChild(element);
    this.reorder();
}

function reorder()
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < combo.length; i++)
    {
        var element:DisplayObject = combo[i];
        element.x = OFFSET_X + (i * SEP_X);
        element.y = OFFSET_Y;
    }
}
```

And this is how I have my truecombo and its contents created.

```
var fireb:firebtn = new firebtn();
var spiritb:spiritbtn = new spiritbtn();
var earthb:earthbtn = new earthbtn();
var windb:windbtn = new windbtn();
var combo:Array=new Array();

const truecombo:Array = [fireb,windb,spiritb,windb,earthb,fireb];
```

Sorry for the lack of comments, I'd guess it's pretty self-explanatory. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `combo[o]` & `truecombo[o]` are two instances of the same class & you want them to be matched. If that is the case you may consider :

```
getQualifiedClassName(combo[o]) == getQualifiedClassName(truecombo[o])
```

To match the way you did, you must ensure the objects lying inside truecombo be referring to the same ones on stage & not new instances.

---

**EDIT:**

It seems you do not break the loop when the match is a success. Use this instead :

```
function checkthis(e:Event)
{
    for(var o:int=0;o<= combo.length; o++) 

      if((combo[o] == truecombo[o]) && (combo.length==truecombo.length)) {

        equal=true;

        break;
      }     

      if (equal) {

        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkthis);

        endSeq();
      }
}
```

Comment: I first declare my vars using `var fireb:firebtn=new firebtn();` (for example) and then fill my truecombo with them...  and then when the user clicks on a symbol on the screen I use `addChild(fireb)`...so I'd guess they are the same instances.

Comment: This returns as true without even clicking on any of the buttons. Check my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simple loop:

```
var equal:Boolean=true
if(combo.length == truecombo.length) {
    for(var i:int=0; i<combo.length; i++) {
        if(combo[i] != truecombo[i]) {
            equal=false;
            break;
        }
    }
} else {
    equal=false;
}

if(equal) {
    //do whatever
}
```

This assumes both are equal, until we find out otherwise. So if the lengths are different, they are not equal. If the i<sup>th</sup> element is different, they are not equal.

In the end, you check if your flag `equal` is true and do whatever you want to do.

Comment: Doesn't work as well..I added some info to my original question.